# Google Static Maps API showing wrong image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I've successfully implemented the Google Static Maps API on a webpage. It works well on hundreds of locations. Example of a working call is:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=Circus+Krone%2C+Marsstra%C3%9Fe+43+%2C+80335+M%C3%BCnchen%2C+DE&markers=color:red%7CCircus+Krone%2C+Marsstra%C3%9Fe+43+%2C+80335+M%C3%BCnchen%2C+DE&zoom=14&size=580x200

BUT: There are two locations where the API returns wrong images. Example:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=Zorlu+Center%2C+%2C+34340+Istanbul%2C+TR&markers=color:red%7CZorlu+Center%2C+%2C+34340+Istanbul%2C+TR&zoom=14&size=580x200

The links to Google Maps for those locations work correctly:

maps.google.de/maps?saddr=&daddr=Zorlu+Center%2C+%2C+34340+Istanbul%2C+TR&hl=de

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong with the two not working image sources?

Cheers
Philipp

Comment: We can't see the links due the API key, can you provide screenshots and code/image paths or something ?

Comment: Try http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=Zorlu+Yapi+Center+Istanbul,+TR&markers=color:red%7CZorlu+Yapi+Center+Istanbul,+TR&zoom=14&size=580x200, is that what you are looking for? Just added 'Yapi' in the URL. Guess static map is not as good as guessing what you are looking for as maps.google.de is.

Comment: You map is in the atlantic ocean!  I found that if I removed Zorlu Center from the marker definition, you get the correct map. It does seem like you might have hit a bug in the google API:  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center=Zorlu Center, 34340+Istanbul, TR&markers=color:red|34340+Istanbul,TR&zoom=14&size=580x200

Comment: Hum, even w/o the full name of the center (missing Yapi), it should still have dropped the marker at the address in Instanbul and not the Atlantic ocean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

static-maps use geocoding to locate addresses, you may see here that the given string didn't return a geocode-result: http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v3-geocoder-tool.html#q%3DZorlu%20Center%2C%20%2C%2034340%20Istanbul%2C%20TR

Google-Maps is able to locate the string, because it also integrates Places.

So what's wrong: the provided address currently isn't geocodable

Comment: Ok that's great. Thank you. I added a field to the CMS where my customer can add a separate search string for the geocoding request if something goes wrong.